# How to get a list of all tables in two different databases

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I'm trying to create a little SQL script (in SQL Server Management Studio) to get a list of all tables in two different databases. The goal is to find out which tables exist in both databases and which ones only exist in one of them.

I have found various scripts on SO to list all the tables of *one* database, but so far I wasn't able to get a list of tables of multiple databases.

So: is there a way to query SQL Server for all tables in a specific database, e.g. `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE databaseName='first_db'` so that I can join this with the result for another database?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order to compare the two lists, you can use [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx#CodeSpippet2), which will show you the tables that are present in both databases as well as those that are only present in one of them:

```
SELECT *
FROM database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES db1
  FULL JOIN database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES db2
    ON db1.TABLE_NAME = db2.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY COALESCE(db1.TABLE_NAME, db2.TABLE_NAME)
```

You can also add `WHERE db1.TABLE_NAME IS NULL OR db2.TABLE_NAME IS NULL` to see only the differences between the databases.

Comment: +1 Cool, I could have sworn this didn't work!  Even works with the SQL Server specific `db1.sys.tables`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can only query tables for the active database.  But you could store them in a temporary table, and join the result:

```
use db1
insert #TableList select (...) from sys.tables
use db2
insert #TableList2 select (...) from sys.tables
select * from #TableList tl1 join Tablelist2 tl2 on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, this is the query I finally used (based on Andriy M's answer):

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables db1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables db2
    ON db1.TABLE_NAME = db2.TABLE_NAME
  ORDER BY db1.TABLE_NAME
```

To find out which tables exist in db2, but not in db1, replace the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, and to find out both, you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead.